# Why doesn't android recognize the locale as RTL when set programmatically?

Tags: android, localization, locale, globalization, right-to-left

I have written a multi-lingual app.

I have different `values` folder for different languages like `values-fa` and `values-ru`. As some of these languages like Farsi and Arabic are RTL, I used a different layout design by putting some other layout *.xml* files in a folder `layout-ldrtl` beside the main `layout` folder.

I also put a file named `is_right_to_left.xml` int a folder named `values-ldrtl` which defines a variable like this:

```
<bool name="is_right_to_left">true</bool>
```

I have the same file in `values` folder and set the variable value to `false` there.

Whenever in the code I need to know, I use this line to understand if current locale is a RTL one or not:

```
isRightToLeft = context.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_right_to_left);
```

I've tested the app with different device configs and everything works like charm. For example setting device language to Farsi causes the app to read the strings from `values-fa` and the layouts from `layout-ldrtl`, while when Arabic is set for device, values are read from `values-ar` and the layouts are also read from `layout-ldrtl` because both of them are RTL languages. It of-course works correctly for LTR languages too. That's what I want.

The problem occurs when I set the locale of the app programmatically. This is the code I wrote in `onCreate()` method of my `MainActivity`:

```
Locale myLocale = new Locale("fa");
Resources res = getResources();
DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
conf.locale = myLocale;
res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
```

Now, the values are read correctly according to the language, but `layout-ldrtl` and `values-ldrtl` are never read. So, the app would load in LTR design because of wrong *.xml* files and wrong value of `isRightToLeft` variable.
One solution I've tested is putting those *.xml* files in each language layout folder separately, and it works. But I hope to get a better and neater way of solving the problem.
And besides the solution, why does android act in this way?

Comment: Do you need to do this programmatically,  or are you just testing your app? If that latter, check out http://lifehacker.com/enable-androids-secret-right-to-left-layout-if-youre-le-1676267178

Comment: @petey I need to do it programmatically. One case is letting the user to choose the app language. Thanks for answer though.

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
Resources res = getResources();
 Configuration newConfig = new Configuration( res.getConfiguration() );
 Locale locale = new Locale("fa");
 Locale.setDefault(locale);
 newConfig.locale = locale;
 newConfig.setLayoutDirection( locale );
 res.updateConfiguration( newConfig, null );
```

Comment: Thanks, It's a good answer and it works, but only for API 17+. Actually, I did the whole two-layout-folder way for minus 17 API support.

Comment: I up-voted the answer, but didn't mark it as accepted. Waiting for a solution that may work for previous APIs as well.